# What are large read requests in sshfs and is it recommended to enable them?

Tags: sshfs

sshfs has the following option:

> ```
>   -o large_read
>          issue large read requests (2.4 only)
> ```

What exactly does this do and how large are large read requests?

Would it be recommended generally or specifically for me to enable this (and is it enabled by default)?
Use: I use sshfs to edit a lot of code.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Large read requests are only valid for FUSE version 27+ and Linux kernels not fresher than 2.4 (2.6 onwards use dynamic sizing).

From http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man8/mount.fuse.8.html:

```
large_read
      Issue  large  read  requests.   This can improve performance for
      some filesystems, but can also degrade performance. This  option
      is only useful on 2.4.X kernels, as on 2.6 kernels requests size
      is automatically determined for optimum performance.
```

For editing code, you won't benefit much from this option. Chances are, you don't have an ancient 2.4-something kernel.